# How to show user current location on google maps detected by WP7 gps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i want to plot/show current location of user on google map, where as location detected by WP& gps. thanks in advance

Comment: i used only bing maps, but now i want to know how google maps are used for this purpose

Comment: @Aqib Saeed - Check the Google documentation I do believe its all done with javascript. There should be a C# library on codeplex I believe that basically is a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps API documentation is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html).

I used the following code in a little (desktop) app of mine, you just need to feed the appropiate set of coordinates.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var latlng;
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var zoom;

    function Init() {
        lat = 40.632915;
        lng = -8.68929;
        zoom = 18
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var options = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
   }
</script>
```